# How to get the child nodes from grails.converters.deep.XML

Tags: grails

I have an xml type grails.converters.deep.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <customer>
    <name>A</name>
    <age>1</age>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name>B</name>
    <age>2</age>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name>C</name>
    <age>3</age>
  </customer>
</list>
```

How do I get each customers and how do I convert it to customer domain object?

Thanks,

Nimmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the deep converters have been deprecated. The new way is supposed to be something like:

XML.use( 'deep' ){ ... }

http://johnrellis.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/grails-and-json-are-pretty-groovy.html

But you should really be using the new render as json functionality in grails 2

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#xmlAndJSON